# Function for returning cases that are unique between data sets

Tags: r

I'm working with data from a longitudinal survey that has a big number of realised waves.

In this phase, I'm checking how many new IDs (cases) are in each subsequent wave (i.e. in wave2 in comparison with wave1, wave2 vs wave3, wave3 vs wave4 etc.). **Each wave has its own data set.**

I created a code that is working fine for manually specified waves. It looks like this:

```
# Create example data
wave1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5))
wave2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,6,7))
wave3 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,6,8))

# In this step I'm taking out the IDs from the first wave                    
idwave1 <- as.vector(wave1$ID)

# In this step I exclude the non-unique IDs from the subsequent wave (wave2) so I can get the number of unique IDs
wave2unique <- wave2[! wave2$ID %in% idwave1, ]

# Now I apply the same procedure for the wave2 and wave3 
idwave2 <- as.vector(wave2$ID)
wave3unique <- wave3[! wave3$ID %in% idwave2, ]
```

However, after this, I stuck with creating some function that will do it for all waves automatically because I don't know to handle the situation that there is a different data set for each wave.

Comment: Is each `wave` a separate `data.frame`? Do you want to compare all waves-vs-waves?

Comment: Yes, I created a separate `data.frame` for each data set. And I would like to always compare just one wave (waveX) and the next wave after that one (waveX+1). Not all waves-vs-waves.

Comment: You should probably give an example with more than two waves and clarify how you want the output to look. My guess is that this works: `library(data.table); unique(rbindlist(list(wave1,wave2), idcol="wave"), by="ID")`. Or in base R: bind rows with an wave id col; drop duplicates in terms of `ID`...

Comment: I updated my example. Basically, I just always need to use the subsequent pair of waves (i.e. wave2 vs wave3, wave3 vs wave4 etc.). Regarding the output, I would like to have objects that contains the unique IDs as it is in the example (i.e. wave2unique, wave3unique etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in a single table (as it probably should be)...

```
library(data.table)
wDT = rbindlist(list(wave1, wave2, wave3), idcol = "wave")

    wave ID
 1:    1  1
 2:    1  2
 3:    1  3
 4:    1  4
 5:    1  5
 6:    2  1
 7:    2  2
 8:    2  3
 9:    2  6
10:    2  7
11:    3  1
12:    3  2
13:    3  3
14:    3  6
15:    3  8
```

Then do an anti-join:

```
wDT[!.(wave + 1L, ID), on=.(wave, ID)]

   wave ID
1:    1  1
2:    1  2
3:    1  3
4:    1  4
5:    1  5
6:    2  6
7:    2  7
8:    3  8
```

For dplyr instead of data.table, there's `bind_rows` (like `rbindlist`) and `anti_join` (like the `x[!i]`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeking something below?

```
wave_ls = list(wave1, wave2, wave3)

f = function(LIST) {
    out = list()
    for (i in 1:(length(LIST) - 1)) {
        wave1 = LIST[[i]]
        wave2 = LIST[[i + 1]]
        out[[i]] = wave2[!wave2$ID %in% wave1$ID,]
        names(out)[i] = paste0('wave', i+1, 'unique')
    }
    out
}

f(wave_ls)
$wave2unique
[1] 6 7

$wave3unique
[1] 8
```